# axios paramsSerializer with brackets

Tags: typescript, axios, query-string

I've trying to make my url

`http://localhost:54700/api/patient/delete?id=5d43e980eb3b00005300493d`

to

`http://localhost:54700/api/patient/delete/5d43e980eb3b00005300493d`

So I tried using paramsSerializer

```
  return await axios.get<any, T>(url, {
    params,
    paramsSerializer: params => {
      return queryString.stringify(params, {arrayFormat: 'brackets'});
    }
  });
```

Same as the axios official document says, but

`function stringify(obj?: ParsedUrlQueryInput, sep?: string, eq?: string, options?: StringifyOptions): string;`
 as you can see second parameter is not an object, but string.

How to transfer my url to `http://localhost:54700/api/patient/delete/5d43e980eb3b00005300493d`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to overcomplicate things with `params` and `paramsSerializer`? I would just write something like this:

```
const patientId = '5d43e980eb3b00005300493d';
const url = `http://localhost:54700/api/patient/delete/${encodeURIComponent(patientId)}`;
return axios.get(url);
```

As far as your original problem, I think the issue is that the Axios example is using the [`query-string`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) NPM package, while you're using attempting to use the `querystring` core Node library. Both of those modules provide a `stringify()` function but accept different parameters.