# Axios convert get query url into a simple forward slash url

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios

I have been trying to figure out what is the best way to perform this simple get request the API is expecting a url like **endpoint/foo/bar*** when I perform my get request following the axios documentation the url gets transform into **endpoint/?value1=foo&value2=bar**

What are the best standards to change or transform the params object with out bloating the function?

```
    // Current output http://localhost:8888/endpoint/?value1=foo&value2=bar
    // Expected url by server http://localhost:8888/endpoint/foo/bar/
    // NodeJS api endpoint/:foo/:bar

    axios.get('http://localhost:8888/endpoint/', {
      params: {
        value1: 'foo',
        value2: 'bar',
      },
    })
    .then( res => {
      console.log( res, 'success' );
    })
    .catch( err =>  {
      console.log(err, 'error');
      // error 404 not found
      // http://localhost:8888/endpoint/?value1=foo&value2=bar
    })
```

I tried this approach but I do think this will not be appropriate

`// axios.get('http://localhost:8888/endpoint/'+this.form.value1+'/'+this.form.value2+')`

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), but basically, yes. Concat the url and the values.

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57470264/axios-paramsserializer-with-brackets

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the query to the url. If you want to pass parameter in sub directory-
-use this approch `` axios.get(`url/${value1}/${value2}`) ``